# Do I still have to water my plants while it's raining?

Tags: animal-crossing-city-folk

In Animal Crossing: City Folk, I sometimes find dying plants while it's raining.  Do I still need to water them manually, or will the rain bring them back to life?

Comment: Arg, thanks for reminding me I should play this game again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not have to worry about manually watering plants while it's raining *or* while it's snowing! Both of these forms of precipitation will properly hydrate your plants without the need to run around with your watering can.